# Unable to pass Current Object Value to sibling component in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

i have 2 sibling components NavBar and ProductAdd. i have created a service in NavBar which returns the userData through nodejs from MongoDb. The issue is that i want to pass value of one object to ProductAdd and when i tried that it passes null. I dont know what is the thing wrong that i am doinf here. i jsut want to use the name and id of the current logged in for my next work/purpose

```
NavBar code ==>
     async chechkLogin(emailL, passwordL)
      {
        //Getting email and password from html template
        await this.userAcc.chechkLogin(emailL, passwordL)
        .subscribe((res) => {
          this.userName =res.name
        })

      }

ProductAdd Code ==>
    constructor(public userData:NavbarComponent) {
        console.log("Name = >" , this.userData.cUserName.subscribe(message => console.log("CurrentUserName =", message)))
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more code, So that we can assist you.

Comment: Hm, why do you use async await with RxJS? How it helps in your case, it isn't promise and at best it wont give results, but it can break code performance.

As I see, you understand DI in Angular wrong. Don't try to inject sibling component. Use common service for these ones.